# Unexpected results while filtering query with equal, contains, startswith and endswith

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

`SELECT value count(1) from c where c.FormName = "Newsletter"` returns 2191

`SELECT value count(1) from c where contains (c.FormName, "Newsletter")` returns 697

`SELECT value count(1) from c where startswith(c.FormName, "Newsletter")` returns 2191

`SELECT value count(1) from c where endswith(c.FormName, "Newsletter")` returns 701

I was expecting all those requests to returns the same value 2191, but `contains` and `endswith`return an unexpected value.

Is this normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is normal yes. All of these queries will consume some RUs. The RUs that will be consumed are different for each query because their "load" is different.

When you're doing `SELECT value count(1)` you're forcing Cosmos to return all of it's results in a single query. However, Cosmos DB only returns paginated results by design. This pagination also helps to spread the load across many queries and aggregate them on the client site. `SELECT value count(1)` won't allow for such aggregation so the response you get is the number before your request run out of RUs.

If you did `SELECT c.id from c where blablabla` and you used the `while(query.HasMoreResults)` & `query.ExecuteNextAsync()` approach and aggregated the count on the client side, you should be getting the same numbers.